# Install cmake for specific user on linux cluster

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cmake

I have installed cmake in my home/user/bin directory of a cluster and would like to set this newly installed cmake as default for my account on the cluster I am working on because the current cmake version that is default is out of date (2.6 version) and I need 2.8 or higher. Hence I would like to know which environment variable to set to make my local version of cmake as default. I am really lost with this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just mean setting PATH like: `PATH=/home/user/bin;$PATH`? So that when you type `cmake` you run the one you built and installed?

Comment: my question was do I need to set path along with some other variable or just PATH.

Comment: Setting PATH that way will make running `cmake` launch the one you compiled. Whether that is enough to get that cmake to function properly depends on cmake itself and what other things cmake installed and how and what uses them.

Comment: yes that was my question as I have modified the PATH variable to point to the updated version of cmake but I still get the same error.

Comment: It worked now. Didn't work before for some reason. I closed the session then ssh in again and reset PATH variable in the exact same way, and it ran this time. Thanks for your help. I don't know why it was being weird before.